# Growing the Root Partition of a Live Boot USB stick

Tags: partition, live-usb

I've created a live boot USB stick using unetbodtin, in order to update a computer whose update tool runs exclusively in Ubuntu. The problem is, the update tool insists on unpacking its files in the root partition, and unetbootin only set aside 8GB for the root partition. (I need about double that much space.)

How do give the root partition more space?